# Cleaning text (remove stop words, punctuation etc) from Excel file in R

Tags: r, text

For my master thesis I am analyzing courses at a university. I have 1134 courses (as rows) with 3 variables (as columns). Due my little experience with R I am struggling with writing the code for it. Here's more information and in I have a sample of the database attached as a image.

[image]

Column 1 is course name
Column 2 is course description
Column 3 is learning outcomes

I want to clean the data and remove stop words, punctuation and other irrelevant characters. I do this with the following code:

```
rm(list=ls());
library(readxl);
library(MASS);
library(nnet);
library(NLP);
library(tm);
database <- read_excel("/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/TU e Innovation Management /Thesis/testdatabasematrix.xlsx");

#name columns
colnames(database)[1] <- "Name";
colnames(database)[2] <- "Description";
colnames(database)[3] <- "LearningOutcomes";

#replace punctuation
database2 <- gsub(pattern = "\\W", replace = " ", database)
#replace digits
database2 <- gsub(pattern="\\d", " ", database2)
#everything to lower
database2 <- tolower(database2)

#until here everything fine
database2 <- removeWords(database2, stopwords());

#When I try to save the database in a data frame, the output is merely 3 observations of 1 variable instead of 1141 obs. of 3 variables
database2 <- data.frame(database2)
```

I hope you can help me :). If you require more information, please say so and I'll provide it of course.

Best,
Christiaan

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you post the result of `dput(head(database,10))` to have a minimal reproducible dataset to work with?

Comment: Apologies for not including the dataset. How can I include the full dataset next time in the best manner?

Comment: If you can post your data, you can `dput(your_data)` and post the output here, or you can create some fake data similar to yours that it's possible to copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider also the `tidytext` and `dplyr` package, that's definetely nice:

```
# some data similar to yours
database <- data.frame(Name = c('Aalto Fellows II', 'Aalto introduction to Services'),
                       Description = c('This course is a lot of words I do not know.','Service economy, whatever it does mean.'),
                       LearningOutcomes = c('Aalto Fellows, which are the smartest, learn.','Knowing what does Service economy means.'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# cool packages
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

# here the text transformations for titles
title <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$Name) %>%        # as tibble
         unnest_tokens(word, text)%>%                                     # remove punctuations, lowercase, put words in column
         anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word")) %>%               # remove stopwords
         group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))  # now all in a row!

# here the text transformations for descriptions
description <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$Description) %>%
               unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%  
               anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word"))  %>%
               group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))

# here the text transformations for learning outcomes
learningoutcomes <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$LearningOutcomes) %>% 
                    unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
                    anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word"))  %>%
                    group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))

# now the full dataset
database2 <- title %>% left_join(description, by = 'line') %>% left_join(learningoutcomes, by = 'line')
colnames(database2) <- c("line","Name","Description","LearningOutcomes")
database2

# A tibble: 2 x 4
   line Name                        Description     LearningOutcomes             
  <int> <chr>                       <chr>           <chr>                        
1     1 aalto fellows ii            lot words       aalto fellows smartest learn 
2     2 aalto introduction services service economy knowing service economy means
```

And you can convert it to a data.frame with `data.frame()`.

Comment: Thank you my dear problem solver, this worked perfectly! Also thanks for reminding me that I should include the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `removeWords` requires a vector of character as first argument. So maybe

```
for (x in colnames(database2)) database2[,x] <- removeWords(database2[,x], stopwords())
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given a sample dataset to work with, I have created one.
This solution also employs the tidytext and dplyr packages but slightly different from above. In this case, you work directly with the dataframe and maintain the dataframe as you go on.

```
# Create dataframe    
database <- data.frame("Name" = c("Hello how, are , you.", "I am fine thank you!"),
                           "Description" = c("installation of package ‘tibble’",
                                             "package ‘readxl’ successfully unpacked "),
                           "LearningOutcome" = c("Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive",
                                                 "TU e Innovation Management")


# Take off stop words
data(stop_words)

database_stopwords <- database %>%
  filter(!Name %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  filter(!Description %in% stop_words$word) %>%
  filter(!LearningOutcome %in% stop_words$word)

# Convert to lower
database_lower <- database_stopwords %>% mutate(
  Name = tolower(Name),
  Description = tolower(Description),
  LearningOutcome = tolower(LearningOutcome)
)

# Take off punctuation and others
database_lower$Name = gsub("\\W|\\d|http\\w?", " ", database_lower$Name, perl = T)
database_lower$Description = gsub("\\W|\\d|http\\w?", " ", database_lower$Description, perl = T)
database_lower$LearningOutcome = gsub("\\W|\\d|http\\w?", " ", database_lower$LearningOutcome, perl = T)
```

Comment: I have used the solution below. However, many thanks for your answer and also the feedback that I should include my dataset.